# average ( working with arraylist ) java

Tags: java

i'm trying to display the average mark of students, but it's display the wrong number, this is what i've tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Course
{

  private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();  

// return the average mark in the course

  public double average()
  {
        double average = 0.0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < people.size(); i++)
        {
            int tmark = people.get(i).getMark() ; 
            {
                average = tmark / i;
            }       
        }
        return average;
  }

}
```

Comment: Either there is some code missing, or this makes no sense at all. Why the block around the avarage assignment? The code here basically says: `Average = Mark of last student / number of students in list`

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the average of a sequence of numbers "by hand", ie, with only pen, paper and your brain? You could start by describing step-by-step how you would do that. Your code makes no sense at all -- the problems go far beyond lack of understanding on how to deal with lists in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you are not calculating average.. you have to divide by the size after summing all the values:

```
public double average()
{
     double average = 0.0;
     for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)  {
         average += people.get(i).getMark() ; 
     }
     return average/people.size();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `get()` is 0-based, not 1-based.

Second, you need to divide the whole sum by `people.size()` rather than `i`, or else first student becomes way more important than 100th one.

**Update:** and third, the current code only considers the very last student, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

You need to work through your code on paper. You are doing something very peculiar. Get a bit of paper, write down an example array of Students (or just marks), and then work through your loop one iteration at a time. And answer these questions

- What is the value of each variable at the beginning of the loop?
- What is the value of each variable at the end of each loop?
- How would you calculate the average on your own with a pen and paper?
- How can the above point be translated into a for loop? Does all the work need to be done in the for loop?

One last point. It should be noted that the first element in an ArrayList or array is at index 0 and that the last is at index (size-1).

eg.

```
index:   0    1    2
array: ['a', 'b', 'c']
size or length: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
public double average()
  {
        double average = 0.0;


        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
        {
            int tmark = people.get(i).getMark() ; 
            {
                average += tmark;
            }       
        }
        average /= people.size();

        return average;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the index of `ArrayList` in java starts with 0.

However, you might want to use a [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in here instead. Replace:

```
for (i = 1; i < people.size(); i++)
```

with

```
for (Student s : people)
```

to sum the total grades, and then divide with `people.size()` as suggested by @alf.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
double total = 0d;
for(Student student : people) {
    total += student.getMark();
}
double average = total / (double)people.size();
```